# changing display in an element of class by onclick method in javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick

These code don't work.

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("circle");
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].onclick = function(){ alert("hello!");};
}
```

Comment: can you please provide the html?

Comment: Why are you looping?

Comment: atleast the part you are trying to manipulate

Comment: because he has getelements not getelement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("circle");
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].onclick = function() {
    this.style.opacity = 0
  };
}
```

```css
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 20px;
  float: left;
  transition: all .3s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Comment: Really nice answer, you conveyed it better than I was able to do. The next time I will answer the way you did.

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way better:

```
for ( i = 0; i < x; i++) {
   x[i].addEventListener('click', function() { alert('Hello World') });
}
```

Comment: <body>
    <div>
        <div id="scorePanel">
            <div id="score">Your score: 0</div>
            <div id="bestScore">Best score:</div>
        </div>
            <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
</body>

Comment: <style>
        .circle{
            width: 80px;
            height: 65px;
            border-radius: 40px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background-color: pink;
            border: 1px solid silver;
            margin-left: 20px;
            margin-top: 40px;
            float: left;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>

Comment: what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: actually I wanna change display the circles to none and hide them,

Comment: so inside the function type x[i].style.display='none';

Comment: this will hide them